# Uploading image from Android to server with okhttp multipart

Tags: android

Here is how I get the image from photo library:

```
private void presentPhotoSelector() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
    intent.setType("image/*");
    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 0 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null) {
        mSelectedPhotoUri = data.getData();
        try {
            Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContext().getContentResolver(), mSelectedPhotoUri);
            photoCircleImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            photoCircleImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            selectPhotoButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            uploadImageToServer(mSelectedPhotoUri);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is how I try to upload it:

```
public class JSONResponse {
    boolean userUploadedProfileImage;
    User user;
}

private void uploadImageToServer(Uri selectedPhotoUri) {
    if (selectedPhotoUri == null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "uploadImageToServer: selectedPhotoUri is null");
        return;
    }
    if (!AuthService.getInstance(mContext).isLoggedIn()) {
        Log.d(TAG, "uploadImageToServer: User not logged in");
        return;
    }
    showLoading("Laster opp bilde...", "Vennligst vent mens prosess foregår");
    File file = new File(selectedPhotoUri.getPath());
    final MediaType MEDIA_TYPE_JPG = MediaType.parse("image/jpeg");
    OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
    RequestBody requestBody = new MultipartBody.Builder()
            .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
            .addFormDataPart("file", "image.jpg",
                    RequestBody.create(MEDIA_TYPE_JPG, file))
            .build();
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + AuthService.getInstance(mContext).getToken())
            .url(Config.URL + "/api/user/upload-profile-image")
            .post(requestBody)
            .build();
    okHttpClient.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, final IOException e) {
            getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    hideLoading();
                }
            });
            Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: response failed: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
            getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    hideLoading();
                }
            });
            String responseBodyString = response.body().string();
            Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: responseBodyString: " + responseBodyString);
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            SettingsFragment.JSONResponse jsonResponse = gson.fromJson(responseBodyString, SettingsFragment.JSONResponse.class);
            if (jsonResponse != null) {
                UserService.getInstance(mContext).setMyUser(jsonResponse.user);
                Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: jsonResponse.userUploadedProfileImage: " + jsonResponse.userUploadedProfileImage);
                Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: jsonResponse.user: " + jsonResponse.user.toString());
            }
        }
    });
}
```

This does not work, the loader never stops spinning and on server side I get this error: `multipart: NextPart: client disconnected`

However, if I change the code above from:

```
File file = new File(selectedPhotoUri.getPath());
```

to:

```
String file = selectedPhotoUri.getPath();
```

Then request is successful, however, when I try to open the image on a browser it says "the image cannot be displayed because it contains errors". When I look at the database I can see that it interpreted its mime type as: application/octet-stream, and not image/jpeg.

I am stuck and I don't know what to do.

I am now getting this error on console: `onFailure: response failed: /-1/1/content:/media/external/images/media/69/ORIGINAL/NONE/656735600 (No such file or directory)`

I am running this on a simulator, if that helps.

Comment: try this  
    MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file", "image.jpg",
                    RequestBody.create(MEDIA_TYPE_JPG, file)) 
instead of 
    new Multipart.Builder() .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
            .addFormDataPart("file", "image.jpg",
                    RequestBody.create(MEDIA_TYPE_JPG, file))
            .build();

Comment: How do I use that in the request?

Comment: I get incompatible types, RequestBody and MultipartBody.Part

Answer (score 0):

One way is:
You have to convert Bitmap to Base64(String) and send that base64 to server.

Comment: Thanks. Could you provide example code? I am new to Android.

Comment: public static String bitmapToBase64(Bitmap bitmap) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, byteArrayOutputStream);
        byte[] byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
        return Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
    }

Comment: I get mime type: text/plain; charset=utf-8 on serverside when I do this, and image is being uploaded but cant be shown because it says it contains errors.

Comment: MediaType JSON = MediaType.parse("application/json;charset=utf-8");

Comment: Change your MediaType to this.

Comment: or try "MediaType JSON = MediaType.parse("text/plain;charset=utf-8");"

Comment: Now I am getting this message: onFailure: response failed: /-1/1/content:/media/external/images/media/69/ORIGINAL/NONE/656735600 (No such file or directory)

Comment: Use this when you are making builder :-     
builder.addFormDataPart("file", "image.jpeg", RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/jpeg"),file ));